# How do I build a Drupal's View that shows access information

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views

I need to create a Views of selection of nodes, some of which the current user may or may not have access to.  What I would like to be able to do is, known what the access is to a node, print out either a link to the node, or a statement letting them know there is no access to that node without certain conditions met first.

I had thought this was a pretty simple matter, but on attempting it, I don't know how to proceed.  Anyone know how to create such a Views?

**Update:**

---

Looks like this might be a simple matter of using the [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield)  module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the simplest solution I found was to use the [Views Custom Field module](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) to check if the user has access to the node and depending on that, generating output:

```
if (node_access('view', $data->nid)) {
//...
}
```